# Restart notification on foreground on Huawei device after user removes it by swiping(Like Strava/Endomondo)

Tags: android, notifications, huawei-mobile-services, foreground-service

I have an foreground task which shows a notification bar and the purpose is to make this notification bar **unremovable**. The configuration of the notification is:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Notification for app")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContent(notificationView)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
```

although setongoing(true) is applied, the notification can be removed on Huwaei devices(Android 5.1.1). though it works on Samsung J3.

when the notification is swiped, the following screen appears on huawei

[image]

what I have seen on strava/endomondo apps on Huawei devices, they bring back the notification instantly after user swipe remove it.

how can the notification be brought back to foreground after user removes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have been able to restart notification on huawei devices like strava/endomondo does.

For triggering the notification delete event, I had to use setDeleteIntent and pass a pending intent of a receiver class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BootCompleteReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Task")
                .setTicker("Notification")
                .setContent(notificationView)
                .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)   //the delete intent I used
                .setOngoing(true).build();
```

on the receiver onReceive method, I started my foreground service again

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, RTMForegroundService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
```

now, everytime user swipe deletes the notification,  it starts again.

Answer (score 1):

@Sabid Habib answer is correct but instead of using system level broadcast it should use custom local broadcast like defined below along with few optimizations

Define your custom broadcast receiver and also place a static boolean `NotificationService.sEnabled` to check if your required service is already running along with additional checks if you don't want to start service unnecessarily, Also you can send boolean to service `notificationServiceIntent.putExtra(NotificationService.EXTRA_RUN_IN_FOREGROUND, true);` to indicate that service should only restart foreground notification instead of restarting it completely from `onStartCommand`

```
public class NotificationRemovalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String FILTER_NOTIFICATION_REMOVED = "FILTER_NOTIFICATION_REMOVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(NotificationService.sEnabled) {
       Intent notificationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
          notificationServiceIntent.putExtra(NotificationService.EXTRA_RUN_IN_FOREGROUND, true);
          context.startService(notificationServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Add this broadcast receiver for delete notification

```
Intent removeNotificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationRemovalReceiver.FILTER_NOTIFICATION_REMOVED);
    PendingIntent removeNotificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, removeNotificationIntent, 0);


    Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getNotificationChannelId())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setDeleteIntent(removeNotificationPendingIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Define your receiver in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.NotificationRemovalReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FILTER_NOTIFICATION_REMOVED" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```